# Aliasing artifacts during transparent MSAA FBO resolve

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have the following rendering flow:

1. Clear MSAA x8 FBO color attachment (RGBA) with `{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}`
2. Issue single draw call (draw rectangular shape).
3. Bind Resolve FBO (just single RGBA color attachment)
4. Blit MSAA FBO into Resolve FBO.

What I noticed that when I clear MSAA FBO to all zeros, AA still has some aliasing artifacts along the diagonal edges.
But if I clear with  `{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}` ,anti-aliasing looks ok.
To verify that the problem is with alpha channel,I attached color texture to resolve FBO that has GL_RGB format instead of GL_RGBA (same as resolving into screen framebuffer which doesn't show this issue),and in this case, the problem doesn't appear.

So my question is, why does it happen when MSAA RT cleared with zero alpha?
And how can I solve it,except clearing alpha to one? Why I need it cleared to zero? Because this is intermediate pass,results of which are used later in alpha compositing.

Here is some of the important parts of the code. I omit pure OpenGL init logic for textures and FBOs setup as it's abstracted behind C++ API,which is well tested in production. Both FBO use texture attachments of RGBA format.

Render loop:

```
 const float clearColorZero[4] = { 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };

 glClearNamedFramebufferfv(msaaFBO, GL_COLOR, 0, clearColorZero);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, msaaFBO);
 glViewport(0, 0,width,height);
 //Bind shader program and mesh:
 BindProgram(mainProg);
 BindMesh(mesh);
 glProgramUniformMatrix4fv(mainProg, 0, 1, GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(matrixMVP)); 
 Draw(mesh);//calls glDrawArrays

 //Resolve MSAA
 glBlitNamedFramebuffer(
                msaaFBO,
                resolveFBO, 
                0, 0, width, height,
                0, 0, width, height,
                GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,GL_NEAREST);
```

Simple fragment shader:

```
 #version 450 core
 out vec4 o_color;
 void main()
 {
    o_color = vec4(1.0,228.0 /255.0,123.0/255.0,1.0); 
 }
```

Blit results with MSAA FBO alpha cleared to zero:

[image]

Blit results with MSAA FBO alpha cleared to one:

[image]

PS: Same happens if I resolve MSAA manually inside shader:

```
#version 450 core
#define NUM_MSAA_SAMPLES 8
layout(binding  = 0) uniform  sampler2DMS colorMap;
out vec4 o_color;
void main()
{
     vec4 color = texelFetch(colorMap,ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);
     for(int i = 1; i < NUM_MSAA_SAMPLES; ++i)
     {
        vec4 samplePoint = texelFetch(colorMap, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), i);
        color += samplePoint; 
     }
     color /= float(NUM_MSAA_SAMPLES); 
     o_color= color;
}
```

Here is magnified version of the screenshots that shows:

MSAA FBO cleared to zero:

[image]

MSAA FBO cleared to one:

[image]

I also can't see any changes even if I disable blending with `glDisable(G_BLEND)`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the difference is between the two?

Comment: Can't you see the aliasing difference on the left edge?These are JPEGs. On TGAs it is seen even better,but SO doesn't support that image type.

Comment: I'd say you just blend it differently, due to the fact that you mix in different alpa values. The MSAA resolution has nothing to do with that. If you use the resulting alpha after resolve to blend, you in a way apply alpha twice. You could probably get around that by using pre-multiplied alpha,

Comment: @derhass as you can see from my render passes,all I do is rendering simple color quad into MSAA FBO cleared to zero,then blit it into non MSAA FBO.glBlitFramebuffer is not affected by blend modes. My default blend mode is GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA (for premult-alpha)

Comment: Ok,I got it. The final texture must be unpremultiplied before saved to image to get correct alpha blend. http://apoorvaj.io/alpha-compositing-opengl-blending-and-premultiplied-alpha.html#toc5

Comment: FYI: Next time use a PNG for your images. They won't have the artifacts.